# How can I find all records where an id is in one array, or another id is in another array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to perform a query that returns all results where an id, or array of ids in an array of ids AND another id, or array of ids, is in another array of ids. Perhaps an example will better explain what I'm  trying to do:

Schema:

```
var somethingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
space_id : String,
title : String,
created : {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
visibility : {
    groups : [{
        type : String,
        ref : 'Groups'
    }],
    users : [{
        type : String,
        ref : 'User'
    }]
}
```

});

Query:

```
something.find({
    space_id: req.user.space_id,
    $and: [
        { $or: [{ "visibility.groups": { $in: groups } }] },
        { $or: [{ "visibility.users": { $in: users } }] }
    ]
    }, function (err, data) {
        return res.json(data);
    });
```

In this example, both `groups` and `users` are arrays of ids. The query above isn't working. It always returns an empty array. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should be including all clauses to OR together in a *single* `$or` array:

```js
something.find({
    space_id: req.user.space_id,
    $or: [{ "visibility.groups": { $in: groups } }, 
          { "visibility.users": { $in: users } }]
}, function (err, data) {
    return res.json(data);
});
```

Which translates to: find all docs with a matching `space_id` AND that have a `visibility.groups` value in `groups` OR a `visibility.users` value in `users`.